# Получение данных об авторизованном пользователе из Laravel в React через fetch

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, laravel, reactjs

Пытаюсь убрать лишние зависимости в приложении заменив `axios` а `fetch`. Работа приложения построена следующим образом. В написанном ранее на `laravel 5.1` сайте добавляются страницы которые написаны с использованием библиотеки `reactjs`.

На реактовской странице понадобилась инфа о текущем залогиненом пользователе. Через `AJAX` обращаюсь к ларавеловскому бекенду за информацией.

**метод на бекенде**

```
public function getUserInfo()
{
  return Auth::user()->toJson();
}
```

- если обращаюсь напрямую в браузере или на реактовской странице через `axios` - корректно получаю инфу по пользователю

  ```
  axios.get('/mlm-get-user-info')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  ```
- если обращаюсь через `fetch`

  ```
  fetch('/mlm-get-user-info')
    .then((response) => {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then((user) => {
      console.log(user);
    });
  ```

  получаю ошибку

  > Call to a member function toJson() on null

Почему так происходит?

Comment: А что в заголовках запросов? Может там причина?

Comment: @IgorGolovin да Вы правы, причина в том что `fetch` не отдавал куки, еще ночью разобрался но уже было не до оформления ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось достаточно тривиальным.

В `laravel`, если пользователь авторизован, каждый запрос на сервер сопровождается куками в которых передается идентификатор сессии полученный при авторизации.

По этому идентификатору и определяется авторизованный пользователь для конкретного запроса.

По умолчанию `fetch` не передает куки в запросе. Чтобы активировать эту функциональность нужно в настройках передать параметр `credentials` со значением  `same-origin`.

**Правильный запрос:**

```
fetch('/mlm-get-user-info', { credentials: "same-origin" })
  .then((response) => {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then((user) => {
    console.log(user);
  });
```